# Tax Verification Pending. Apple Search Ads

Tags: ads, apple-search-ads

I created campaigns in Apple Search Ads.
I created some Ad Groups in every campaign.

Campaign has status `Tax Verification Pending`.
Campaign in this status is already 3 days.

### How to start Campaigns?

Card for payment was connected to this account.

[image: taxVerificationPending]

Comment: Which country your Search Ads Account belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Account settings to another country and change payment card.

Wrong country was Russia, and Russian payment card.

I changed Adress in "Account Settings->Overview->Business Details" to Ukraine.

I changed payment card in "Account Settings->Billing->Active Payment Method" to Ukrainian MasterCard.

Campaign was started.

**Reason of blocking:**

> Thank you for your Apple Search Ads inquiry.
>
> Due to changes to the VAT law in Russia, Apple Search Ads is not
>   currently able to support any customer whose business is based in that
>   country. Beginning December 12, 2018, Search Ads app promotions
>   running in any country or region was paused for businesses based in
>   Russia. We are working toward a resolution and will be in contact if
>   this policy changes.
>
> Best Regards, The Apple Search Ads Team